# .htaccess Rules Removing .php while forwarding real 404s

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

I know little about .htaccess,  What I'm trying to accomplish is two-fold.

1. Allow requests to .php to be called with or without the .php and
   with or without a trailing slash.  For example.

   `/profile.php`  *works*
   `/profile`  *appends .php, works*
   `/profile/`  *append .php so it works*
2. If the file or directory doesn't exist after trying the above, then
   treat as a 404 and redirect to another page.

   `/something` *failure, redirect to /404.php?id=$1 (url requested)*

I have two rules that work separately, but I need to conditionalize these or something.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on

# This works for the PHP part.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.php

# This works for general 404 handling
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php?url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Alternatively, there is `Options +MultiViews` or `ErrorDocument 404` for accomplishing the same. Where did you find the first half? (That's where the problem lies.)

Comment: why do you need to `conditionalize these or something`?

Comment: The "conditionalize" is just my way of saying I really only need one of these to run at a time.  They both operate on "non-existent" files.  If the first set actually finds a .php, then that should be the end of it.  If it doesn't, then it should take those 404s and push to 404.php.

Mario - not sure how this is a duplicate.  I don't see the combination of these two objectives in the answers, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Not sure how to mark a comment as answered, but Multiviews was the answer.  I turned that on, and commented out the first rewriterule and it works like I want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache will automatically append .php to `/profile` and `/profile/` without any mod_rewrite. The only thing you should handle is the 404 page.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php?url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

However, if it's not working for some reason (e.g. apache wasn't configured well):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php?url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```